# Asp.net Application Pool Size Calculation

Tags: asp.net, iis, threadpool

I want to know how does Asp.net application calculate its pool size. I have created a console application in which i have set the Max Pool Size as 20. In that it runs till 32 to 34 times with open connections. After that it says me that Max pool size has reached. I need to know how does asp.net calculate its pool size.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You can't do anything with any answer you're going to get. The pool size also isn't "calculated", it just is there and it can give at max the configured number of connections to your application. The proper answer is _"Close your database connections after you're done with them"_, and then you can figure the question out for yourself.

Comment: OK. I thought that there are some standard calculations. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @CodeCaster , i think it is not just closing the connections , we need also to `Dispose` to dispose/clear the cache after closing the database connection. I've encounter it in my previous work specially when the method behind code is related to generating of reports such as crystal report etc.. disposing the connection is very important after closing the db connections.

Comment: Also if all my connections are closed then too this error is getting triggered. Can you tell me what could be the possible reasons for the same?